# Getting an unknown number of regex elements

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

I have an string that may have several combinations of ANDs and ORs as follow:

```
   string display = "every ((Id2=Event(MachineInfo='M3',UserInfo='U3')) or (Id1=Event(MachineInfo='M2',UserInfo='U2')) and (Id0=Event(MachineInfo='M1',UserInfo='U1')))"
```

Right now I have an inefficient way to catch just the first MachineInfo and UserInfo but I don't know how to get the rest of the elements of the string:

```
 const string machineinfo = @"MachineInfo='(?<MachineInfo>[^']+)";
 const string userinfo = @"UserInfo='(?<UserInfo>[^']+)";

 string machineName = display.Contains("MachineInfo") ?
             Regex.Matches(display, machineinfo)[0].Groups[1].Value : "ANY";
 string userName = display.Contains("UserInfo") ?
             Regex.Matches(display, userinfo)[0].Groups[1].Value : "ANY";
```

What can I do to get all the MachineInfos and UserInfos without knowing the number of ANDs and ORs that I may have in display string??

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your syntax includes nesting with parenthesis. I suggest you don't use regexes to parse this, but instead look into using a proper parser. Regular expressions can't really express this nestedness.

Comment: Do you have any idea of which one?

Comment: I guess ANTLR, but I don't know it well enough to recommend it. hang in there for a while and see what else pops up.

Comment: parboiled seems to be for Java, I am using C#

Comment: I don't like very much the option of using external tools, I am more for a programmatic way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an inefficient/incomplete solution, try yourself to improve the result

```
        MatchCollection aa = Regex.Matches(display, machineinfo);
        foreach (var aaa in aa) {
            //aaa.ToString() 
            //try some thing with object aaa
        }
```

in the above code, object `aaa` will give you `MachineInfo`..try similar with `UserInfo` also and put `?` operator inside foreach loop and try your skill..

Comment: @Manolete: why do you think so?